# Setup of SQL Session in Databricks gives error

Tags: python, databricks

i am trying to practice spark=sql on community edition of databricks,
and using the workbook

https://files.training.databricks.com/courses/spark-sql/latest/amazon/Lessons.dbc

in the third step i am hitting error during setup of SQL Session

this is the command in python session

```
%run "./Includes/Classroom-Setup"
```

this is the log

```
Notebook not found: 
Users/amohammed@xxx.com/Includes/Classroom-Setup. 
Notebooks can be specified via a relative path 
(./Notebook or ../folder/Notebook) or via an absolute 
path (/Abs/Path/to/Notebook). Make sure you are 
specifying the path correctly.

Stacktrace:
/Users/amohammed@shuaa.com/First_Notebook: python
Command took 0.01 seconds -- by amohammed@xxx.com at 
7/7/2018, 9:33:35 PM on Abdulrahman
```

what mistake am i making in setting the context

thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abdul,
Double check you have an active cluster attached to your notebook.

Comment: Thanks Prithvi, it worked properly once notebook is attached to active cluster